# SQL Server y SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Español/Spanish.

Hola a todos, como dice el titulo, estoy confuso sobre sql server y sql server express, siendo que no las puedo diferenciar, además de poder instalar ambas en una misma maquina y utilizar sql management studio.

pregunto, ya que tengo que realizar un proyecto de la universidad sobre datamart, siendo sql server quien almacene los datos y sql express quien realice las consultas sin tocar la DB.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Saludos.

---

English/Ingles.

Hello everyone, as the title says, I'm confused about sql server and sql server express, but I do not have the difference, besides being able to install both in the same sql administration studio.

I ask, since I have to make a project of the university on the datamart, being the server sql who stores the data and the sql express who makes the consultations without touching the database.

I hope you can help me.
Greetings.

Comment: no tienes por que escribir tu pregunta en inglés, esta es la versión en español de SO y por tanto ese es el lenguaje usado

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow es para realizar preguntas concretas de los [temas permitidos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Lo que has publicado actualmente no me deja clara cual es esa duda concreta que tienes y en su forma actual me temo que terminará siendo cerrada por la comunidad. Por favor editala para añadir más detalle.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server es el motor de BD de Microsoft. Por cuestiones de costo/licenciamiento se ofrece en varias ediciones, una de ellas es la SQL Server express edition, que no tiene costo, pero viene limitada en funcionalidades. Para tu proyecto escolar debe de funcionar sin problemas.

Si necesitas saber mas acerca de las ediciones, prueba este link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions